# Ruby scope of DATA after __END__

Tags: ruby

I'm using this Ruby trick with `__END__` and `DATA` to put some data inside my program file:

```
class Foo
  def initialize()
    puts DATA.read.inspect
  end
end
puts DATA.read.inspect
Foo.new
__END__
test
```

This generates the following output:

```
"test"
""
```

I had assumed `DATA` would be the same globally, but inside the class it has no content. How  would I get access to the data after `__END__` inside a class (apart from the obvious and ugly solution using global variables)?

**ADDED:** I see how reading `DATA` twice gives me nothing the second time. I could use `rewind` to get back to the start, but `read` then gives me the entire source code of my program. Is there an easier way to get to just the part after `__END__` on subsequent uses of `DATA`, or would I be better of reading it once and storing it somewhere else for future use?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

DATA is the same. You would get the same output if instead of doing Foo.new you would do DATA.read a second time.

This is because after the first read `DATA` (which is an IO) has reached the end of the stream, so any further reads will return an empty string, unless you append additional data to DATA or rewind `DATA` to the beginning of the stream.

Edit: To seek back to the point right after the `__END__` you have to read `DATA.pos` before performing any reading on `DATA` and then restore `pos` to that value after reading. The easiest solution is probably just doing `FOO = DATA.read` at the beginning of the script and then using `FOO`.

Comment: Doing `FOO = DATA.read` will lose the advantages of an enumerable `IO` object. `FOO = StringIO.new(DATA.read, 'r')` may be preferable? (Do `require 'stringio'` first)

Answer (score -4):

rewind DATA first, because it's a stream.

```
class Foo
  def initialize()
    DATA.rewind
    puts DATA.read.inspect
  end
end
puts DATA.read.inspect
Foo.new
__END__
test
```

Comment: This seems to give me the entire contents of the file, not just the part after `__END__`.