# Need help getting this regex right

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to parse the values separated by commas in these 4 example sources

```
1,'Tambaú','Praça Santo António','Tambaú','12x0',2,'I','EM',12,6,5934,50
2,'Beira Rio','Av. Beira Rio,  Prox. Av Odilon Coutinho','Beira Rio','12x0',2,'I','EM',12,0,7249,0
3,'Cabo Branco','Cabo Branco, Prox. Rua Alice de Almeida','Cabo Branco','12x0',2,'I','EO',12,0,4751,0
901,'teste','teste','teste','Mini-estação de demonstração',1,'I','EO',2,1,97,50`
```

I am using the regex `('?.*?'?),` in Ruby. I can get the first and the last parsed like I want. However the problem with 2nd and 3rd is that there is a comma in the name (Av. Beira Rio,  Prox. Av Odilon Coutinho and Cabo Branco, Prox. Rua Alice de Almeida). With my regex, these come out separated. For example I get Av. Beira Rio and Prox. Av Odilon Coutinho which is not what I want.

EDIT: I should have specified that this is not from a CSV file. It's the parameters to a function from a web page source code.

Comment: Regular expressions are not suitable for this task. Don't use them. Use a CSV parser. [Ruby has one built in](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html).

Comment: @meagar That’s simply not true. **You very most certainly *can* use regexes for this.** There’s just no reason to recreate the wheel.

Comment: @meagar - I should have specified that this is not from a CSV file. It's the parameters to a function from a web page source code.

Comment: @tchrist Yes it simply is true. Regular expressions **"very most certainly" are *not suitable* for this**. I didn't say they *can't* do it, just that they are *not suitable*. "Suitable" doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: Your example is not from a CSV file - but it looks like CSV. Are there any example lines, which are not like CSV? If not, you may use CSV. Let's call it a special kind of **duck typing** - if it looks like CSV, then treat is as CSV.

Comment: @knut - I tried your answer below, it didn't work.

Comment: Can you post a line, where you have problems? Or a MWE (minimal working example), what does not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use CSV and set `:quote_char => "'"` to handle the separator inside your fields:

```
#encoding: utf-8
require 'csv'

input = <<data
1,'Tambaú','Praça Santo António','Tambaú','12x0',2,'I','EM',12,6,5934,50
2,'Beira Rio','Av. Beira Rio, Prox. Av Odilon Coutinho','Beira Rio','12x0',2,'I','EM',12,0,7249,0
3,'Cabo Branco','Cabo Branco, Prox. Rua Alice de Almeida','Cabo Branco','12x0',2,'I','EO',12,0,4751,0
901,'teste','teste','teste','Mini-estação de demonstração',1,'I','EO',2,1,97,50
data

CSV.new(input, :quote_char => "'").each{|data|
  p data.size
  p data  
}
```

---

If you don't have a String but an Array as source, you need a little adaption:

```
#encoding: utf-8
require 'csv'

regexArr = [
  ["1,'TambaÃº','PraÃ§a Santo AntÃ³nio','TambaÃº','12x0',2,'I','EM',12,6,5934,50"], 
  ["2,'Beira Rio','Av. Bei ra Rio, Prox. Av Odilon Coutinho','Beira Rio','12x0',2,'I','EM',12,0,7249,0"], 
  ["3,'Cabo Branco','Cabo Bra nco, Prox. Rua Alice de Almeida','Cabo Branco','12x0',2,'I','EO',12,0,4751,0"], 
  ["901,'teste','teste','test e','Mini-estaÃ§Ã£o de demonstraÃ§Ã£o',1,'I','EO',2,1,97,50"]
]

regexArr.each do |loc| 
  CSV.new(loc.first, :quote_char => "'").each do |data| 
    p data
  end 
end
```

As an alternative you may build a String:

```
input = regexArr.flatten.join("\n")
CSV.new(input, :quote_char => "'").each{|data|
  p data.size
  p data  
}
```

Both methods expect an array with one-element-arrays.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on here. Where does the input string go ?

Comment: Sorry, I used text after `__END__` (stored in `DATA`) to get the data. `DATA` is like a file handle, details see in [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333720/ruby-scope-of-data-after-end). I modified my answer and use now a [Here-Document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Ruby). I hope that's not so confusing.

Comment: I kind of did the same thing as you but I'm not getting any output. I'm not syre if those single quotes are needed around every element for the CSV to be able to parse them. Here's the code

 `regexArr.each do |loc|
  CSV.new(loc[0], :quote_char => "'") do |data|
    puts data
  end  
end`

the regexArr here contains all those strings as an array of array of strings like so in the comment below

Comment: `[["1,'TambaÃº','PraÃ§a Santo AntÃ³nio','TambaÃº','12x0',2,'I','EM',12,6,5934,50"], ["2,'Beira Rio','Av. Bei
ra Rio,  Prox. Av Odilon Coutinho','Beira Rio','12x0',2,'I','EM',12,0,7249,0"], ["3,'Cabo Branco','Cabo Bra
nco, Prox. Rua Alice de Almeida','Cabo Branco','12x0',2,'I','EO',12,0,4751,0"], ["901,'teste','teste','test
e','Mini-estaÃ§Ã£o de demonstraÃ§Ã£o',1,'I','EO',2,1,97,50"]]`

Comment: In your code you create a CSV-object (`CSV.new`) and close it with a block. There is no iterator. You need a `each` before you start the block: `CSV.new(loc[0], :quote_char => "'").each do `. I will extend my answer in a minute.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it with regex, you could do something like :

```
^(([^,]*)(,|$))*
```

and then get the groups

Comment: I think you’ll find that something more like `/'([^']+?)',?|([^,]+),?|,/` will work better, but you’ll have to trim the null fields.

Answer (score 1):

Good luck parsing
[context-free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free) stuff with
regex. Your data looks like `CSV`.

```
CSV.parse("901,'teste','teste','teste','Mini-estação de demonstração',1,'I','EO',2,1,97,50")
=> [["901",
  "'teste'",
  "'teste'",
  "'teste'",
  "'Mini-estação de demonstração'",
  "1",
  "'I'",
  "'EO'",
  "2",
  "1",
  "97",
  "50"]]
```

Comment: This seems like a very good and easier than regex method. However this does not work for my purpose. I'm getting the same problem that I got with regex parsing. It still separates out 'Av. Beira Rio", "  Prox. Av Odilon Coutinho' into two different elements, when it is one name in the original.

`1.9.2p318 :002 > CSV.parse("2,'Beira Rio','Av. Beira Rio,  Prox. Av Odilon Coutinho','Beira Rio','12x0',2,'I','EM',12,0,7249,0")
 => [["2", "'Beira Rio'", "'Av. Beira Rio", "  Prox. Av Odilon Coutinho'", "'Beira Rio'", "'12x0'", "2", "'I'", "'EM'", "12", "0", "7249", "0"]] 
1.9.2p318 :003 > `