# How to print several lines around a matched line in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

My script searches through the files, finds an entry in the log and prints the corresponding line, what i would like to see is the several lines around the match in order to see what happened previously

```
files=Dir.open(Dir.pwd)
files.each do |li|
  next unless File.file? li
  f = File.open(li, "r:windows-1251")
  if f.each do |line|
    next unless line.include? (tag_466) or line.include?(tag_1004)
    a=[]
    a << ["1.#{MAT_1}".aster.console_green, line, "\n"] if line =~ /#{MAT_1}/
    a << ["2.#{MAT_2}".aster.console_green, line, "\n"] if line =~ /#{MAT_2}/
    puts a
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

An example:

```
def match_environment( filename, check_content = 'test', no_of_lines = 4)
  line_pattern = "%1s %5i: %s%"
  File.open(filename, "r:windows-1251") do |f|
    puts "====File #{f.path}===="
    #Contains previous 4 lines
    extract = []
    hit = 0 #flag to print next lines

    f.each_with_index do |line,linno|
      linno += 1  #Start line counting with 1
      extract.shift if extract.size >= no_of_lines  #remove last line
      if line.include? ( check_content )
        #print previous 4 lines
        extract.each_with_index{|pline, index|
          puts line_pattern % [ nil, linno - extract.size + index, pline.chomp ]
        }
        extract = []  #avoid
        puts line_pattern % [ '!', linno, line.chomp ]  #This line has a hit
        hit = no_of_lines #print next four line
      else
        if hit > 0  #put next lines
          puts line_pattern % [ nil, linno,line.chomp ]
          hit -= 1
          puts '   [...]' if hit == 0
        end
        extract << line   #add actual line
      end
    end 
  end #close file

end #match_environment


#Test if we find test anywhere
match_environment( __FILE__, 'test' )

exit  #remove to check directory
#loop on directory
Dir['*'].each do |filename|
  next unless File.file? filename
  match_environment( filename )
end
```

`extract` is an Array with the last n lines (parameter `no_of_lines`). Each new line is appended, previous lines are removed. `extract` is a storage of the previous n lines.

`hit` is a counter to print the next n lines.

One advantage of this solution: If you match your search pattern (in my example it is `'test'`) multiple times, the four lines before and after are only counted from first and last hit.

`line_pattern` is a pattern for the output (flag if the line contains the search string, 5 characters for the line number, followed by the line).

If I execute the script, I get:

```
====File test.rb====
      1:     %
      2:     %
!     3:     def match_environment( filename, check_content = 'test', no_of_lines = 4)%
      4:       line_pattern = "%1s %5i: %s%"%
      5:       File.open(filename, "r:windows-1251") do |f|%
      6:         puts "====File #{f.path}===="%
      7:         #Contains previous 4 lines%
   [...]
     33:     end #match_environment%
     34: %
     35: %
!    36:     #Test if we find test anywhere%
!    37:     match_environment( __FILE__, 'test' )%
     38:     %
     39:     exit  #remove to check directory%
     40:     #loop on directory%
     41:     Dir['*'].each do |filename|%
   [...]
```

Remark: `match_environment( __FILE__, 'test' )` executes the script on the script file itself.

Comment: i get an error `18:in `block (4 levels) in <main>': uninitialized constant Object::LINE_PATTERN (NameError)` -is it working for you knut?

Comment: Yes, it works for me. Did you see the line before the `Dir['*']`? There LINE_PATTERN is defined. I will try to make it a bit more universal  with a method - my edit will follow next time.

Comment: I encapsulated my code in a method and replaced the constant with a variable.

Comment: i get an error -`: uninitialized constant Object::DATA (NameError)`
what DATA is referring to ? `match_environment( DATA, 'test' )`

Comment: I just replaced `DATA` with `__FILE__` - I think thats more clear. But `DATA`should also work. `DATA` is the file handle, starting with text after `__END__`. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333720/ruby-scope-of-data-after-end

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in multiple steps:

1. Read the file into an `Array`
2. Find the matching line indices in that array
3. Implement a method `print_line(ary, index, context)` that prints lines `index-context..index+context` and call it for every index found

Comment: Read the file into an Array- the file are huge -all together about a gig -i'm afraid that would slow down everything.., but thanks for offer thougth